# Openstack RDO can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.3.139

Tags: openstack, rdo

Recently my Openstack (use RDO) has an error. Admin user's password is correct. I can use mysql by "keystone", "root". This is detail(/var/log/keystone/keystone.log) :

```
(OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.3.139' (111)") None None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/common/wsgi.py", line 238, in __call__
    result = method(context, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/token/controllers.py", line 127, in authenticate
    auth_token_data, roles_ref=roles_ref, catalog_ref=catalog_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/common/manager.py", line 44, in _wrapper
    return f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/token/providers/uuid.py", line 386, in issue_v2_token
    self.token_api.get_token(token_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/token/core.py", line 128, in get_token
    token_ref = self._get_token(unique_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 936, in decorate
    should_cache_fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    async_creator) as value:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/core/dogpile.py", line 158, in __enter__
    return self._enter()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/core/dogpile.py", line 98, in _enter
    generated = self._enter_create(createdtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/core/dogpile.py", line 149, in _enter_create
    created = self.creator()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 565, in gen_value
    created_value = creator()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 932, in creator
    return fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/token/core.py", line 140, in _get_token
    return self.driver.get_token(token_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/keystone/token/backends/sql.py", line 46, in get_token
    token_ref = session.query(TokenModel).get(token_id)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 775, in get
    return self._load_on_ident(key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2512, in _load_on_ident
    return q.one()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2184, in one
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2227, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2240, in _execute_and_instances
close_with_result=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2231, in _connection_from_session
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 730, in connection
    close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 736, in _connection_for_bind
    return engine.contextual_connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2490, in contextual_connect
    self.pool.connect(),
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 224, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 387, in __init__
    rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 741, in _do_get
    con = self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 188, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 330, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._creator()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 281, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.3.139' (111)") None None
```

What's wrong with MySQL ? Could someone give me some advice ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure mysql service is running using
`service mysql status`
next make sure it is listening on "10.0.3.139". 
By default mysql listens on localhost. 
To change that edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf and set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and restart the service. This will make it to listen on all the available interfaces.
Finally you have to make sure the mysql database, user and password are configured properly in /etc/keystone/keystone.conf and also that the user/database are created in mysql.

Use the below link for more details.
http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/install-keystone.html